# restricting glob in python versus bash

Tags: python, linux, bash, glob

My program reads a field like *ABC* and tries to convert it into a glob statement.
I am having issues when trying to restrict the data.
Glob doesn't work the same in linux bash vs python glob library:

From bash:

```
bash_level$ ls *FOO*V7*
baz_FOO_V7.txt  baz_FOO_V777.txt 
bash_level$ ls *FOO*V7[![:digit:]]* 
baz_FOO_V7.txt
```

From ipython:

```
In [1]: import glob
In [2]: glob.glob("*FOO*V7*.txt")
Out[2]: ['baz_FOO_V7.txt', 'baz_FOO_V777.txt']
In [3]: glob.glob("*FOO*V7[![:digit:]]*.txt")
Out[3]: []
```

Bottom line: 
Out[3] hasn't the same expected output. 
How can I overcome this issue?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could translate your glob expression into a regular expression:

```
import re
regex=re.compile(r'.*FOO.*V7[^\d].*\.txt')
print filter(lambda x: regex.match(x), glob.glob("*"))
```

Of course, at this point you no longer need `glob` as you could use `os.listdir()` instead.

**EDIT**

Reading the docs for `glob` and [fnmatch](http://docs.python.org/library/fnmatch.html#fnmatch.fnmatch) (which is what glob uses to do matching), it appears that your match could be written as:

```
glob.glob('*FOO*V7[!0123456789]*')
```

as well.

Comment: Thanks @mgilson, but I am expecting that the `*ABC*` field to be filled in by a user in a csv file. The line `r'.*FOO.*V7[^\d].*\.txt'` could look a bit discouraging for the average user (not that `[![:digit:]]` is friendlier, but it's a bit easier to read).

Comment: Many thanks @mgilson! your line `glob.glob('*FOO*V7[!0123456789]*')` hit the spot!

Comment: @dola -- I agree.  It's unfortunate that python's fnmatch doesn't match all shell globbing (although, not all shells glob the same either).  fnmatch also won't handle curly braces (`{}`) which is technically a shell expansion, but the order of expansion is shell dependent (`bash` does it differently than `csh` for example).  I think that you have to just resign yourself to a subset of what bash can do.  (or write your own parser ... yuck ;^) )

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the output of `fnmatch.translate`, which is used in the implementation of `glob.glob`, I think the glob is converted to an incorrect regex:

```
>>> fnmatch.translate("*FOO*V7[![:digit:]]*")
'.*FOO.*V7[^[:digit:]\\].*\\Z(?ms)'
```

Python regular expressions don't handle the `[[:class:]]` syntax; it appears `fnmatch.translate` is limited in the glob patterns in can translate.